# How to color bonds by the strain?

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, computational-chemistry, molecular-structure, software

I need to create a figure of a molecule in which the bonds are colored in a RGB scale according to the values read from a data file. The data file contains, for example, the increase or decrease in the bond length compared to some reference structure. In this way, the intensity in a color range red-white-blue would be given by the difference between the relaxed and unrelaxed bond lengths, similarly to the figure attached.

I have tried to make this figure using jmol, but I didn't have success so far. Could anyone suggest a program that is able to do such figure? Or could someone point out any suggestion of how to do this color maps on chemical bonds?

[image: Color map on graphene structure according to the changes in the bond length. Extracted from the book Nanodevices and Nanomaterials for Ecological Security.]

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

All the best

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) using LATEX syntax. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: This is quite a special request and you probably have better luck contacting the authors of the paper (could you include the reference please) how they obtained this image. None of the programs I work with (molden, chemcraft) seem to be able to do so.

Comment: I guess it should be possible to search for certain distances between two atoms and color those bonds differently with PyMol, but it would involve some scripting.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and suggestions. The problem has been solved using Jmol program. After some discussion in the Jmol mailing list, prof. Robert Hanson suggested a very simple script that can assign colors to the bonds according to the respective length.

PS.: The figure attached to my comment was taken from the book "Nanodevices and Nanomaterials for Ecological Security, Ed. Springer", chapter 5, author Arkady V. Krasheninnikov.

Comment: @Max Pinheiro you should make your comment an answer to your question so it shows up as answered.

Answer (score 4):

[StrainViz](https://github.com/CurtisColwell/StrainViz) is the program that might be useful [[1](https://doi.org/10.1039/D0SC00629G)].

#### Reference

1. Colwell, C. E.; Price, T. W.; Stauch, T.; Jasti, R. Strain Visualization for Strained Macrocycles. *Chem. Sci.* **2020**, 11 (15), 3923–3930. DOI: [10.1039/D0SC00629G](https://doi.org/10.1039/D0SC00629G).